# tables join - performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, self-join

I have table called Employee table which contains data like

```
Manager ManagerType Employee EmployeeType
A       Mgr1        Emp2     cat2
B       Mgr2        Emp3     Cat3
Emp3    Cat3        EmpX     Cat_X
Emp3    Cat3        EmpY     Cat_Y
```

Now I need to get the data linearly based on EmployeeType Column, for which i coded a select command with case statement over EmployeeType and i have around 12 levels of employees for which i need to join Employee table itself 11 times

Apologies, here is the code

```
  select LEVEL0.Manager AS LEVEL0_Manager    
 ,LEVEL0.Employee AS LEVEL0_Employee, LEVEL0.EmployeeType AS LEVEL0_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL1.Employee AS LEVEL1_Employee, LEVEL1.EmployeeType AS LEVEL1_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL2.Employee AS LEVEL2_Employee, LEVEL2.EmployeeType AS LEVEL2_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL3.Employee AS LEVEL3_Employee, LEVEL3.EmployeeType AS LEVEL3_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL4.Employee AS LEVEL4_Employee, LEVEL4.EmployeeType AS LEVEL4_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL5.Employee AS LEVEL5_Employee, LEVEL5.EmployeeType AS LEVEL5_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL6.Employee AS LEVEL6_Employee, LEVEL6.EmployeeType AS LEVEL6_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL7.Employee AS LEVEL7_Employee, LEVEL7.EmployeeType AS LEVEL7_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL8.Employee AS LEVEL8_Employee, LEVEL8.EmployeeType AS LEVEL8_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL9.Employee AS LEVEL9_Employee, LEVEL9.EmployeeType AS LEVEL9_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL10.Employee AS LEVEL10_Employee, LEVEL10.EmployeeType AS LEVEL10_EmployeeType    
 ,LEVEL11.Employee AS LEVEL11_Employee, LEVEL11.EmployeeType AS LEVEL11_EmployeeType    
 INTO #Relation_Level_12    
 from Employee  LEVEL0    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL1 ON LEVEL0.Employee = LEVEL1.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL2 ON LEVEL1.Employee = LEVEL2.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL3 ON LEVEL2.Employee = LEVEL3.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL4 ON LEVEL3.Employee = LEVEL4.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL5 ON LEVEL4.Employee = LEVEL5.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL6 ON LEVEL5.Employee = LEVEL6.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL7 ON LEVEL6.Employee = LEVEL7.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL8 ON LEVEL7.Employee = LEVEL8.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL9 ON LEVEL8.Employee = LEVEL9.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL10 ON LEVEL9.Employee = LEVEL10.Manager    
 LEFT JOIN Employee  LEVEL11 ON LEVEL10.Employee = LEVEL11.Manager    
 where LEVEL0.ManagerType  = 'Mgr1'
```

Employee table got around 30 million records

The question is, would be perform be effective if self join the Employee table 11 times or split up query an join level by level into a temp table and for the next level. I use temp table join with Employee table to form another temp table. like wise 11 times to achieve the same result or the above query is better?

Comment: Use a common table expression (CTE)

Comment: You talk about your SQL but you don't post an example? It's also unnecessary to join to the employee table 11+ times to get what you want, and resorting to temp tables is even worse. Design your database correctly first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive common table expression to get this data.

There is an example that's perfect for your situation on Technet: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This is useful James, Thank you